# adding and multiplying common elements among two data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

I need to do two operations on a data.table

1. Multiply some of the columns with scalars in another data.table (with matching names) by scenario
2. Add columns (with matching names) from another data.table after the multiplication is over.

As an example, here are some sample data.tables I constructed to try it out

Original data.table.

```
> input <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rdatatable/data.table/master/vignettes/flights14.csv"
> flights <- fread(input)
> flights
        year month day dep_delay arr_delay carrier origin dest air_time distance hour
     1: 2014     1   1        14        13      AA    JFK  LAX      359     2475    9
     2: 2014     1   1        -3        13      AA    JFK  LAX      363     2475   11
     3: 2014     1   1         2         9      AA    JFK  LAX      351     2475   19
     4: 2014     1   1        -8       -26      AA    LGA  PBI      157     1035    7
```

Constructed data.tables

```
> DT_mult = data.table(
     scenario = c("fast","slow"),
     distance = c(0.75,2),
     hour = c(0.9,1.5)
)

> DT_add = data.table(
     scenario = c("fast","slow"),
     arr_delay = c(1,2),
     dep_delay = c(-1,3)

> DT_mult
   scenario distance hour
1:     fast     0.75  0.9
2:     slow     2.00  1.5

> DT_add
   scenario arr_delay dep_delay
1:     fast         1        -1
2:     slow         2         3
```

This is not the actual data, there are some other steps that happen in between the operations so I am not trying to do everything in one step. And it will be running in a for loop by scenario (again because some other things are to be done in between)

I tried **Map** based on some searches here, but I think it relies on columns being matched and ordered correctly

```
> Map("*",flights,DT_mult[scenario=='fast',.SD,.SDcols=c("distance","hour")])
Error in .Primitive("*")(dots[[1L]][[6L]], dots[[2L]][[2L]]) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator

> Map("+",flights,DT_add[scenario=='fast',.SD,.SDcols=c("arr_delay","dep_delay")])
Error in .Primitive("+")(dots[[1L]][[6L]], dots[[2L]][[2L]]) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Any ideas on how this can be achieved? This operation will be done thousands of time (for a Monte Carlo simulation) so ideally something with low runtime is better even if the solution is complicated.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please clarify specifically which values should be multiplied by which values.

Comment: Hi Vincent, the columns to be multiplied are the ones with the common column names. For example, I would like to multiply the distance column in flights with the distance column in DT_mult for each scenario in DT_mult. Similarly, arr_delay in DT_add would get added to arr_delay in flights for each scenario. Thanks